# Reemplazar dato en JSON con python

Tags: json

Tengo datos en JSON los cuales obtengo de una base de datos, existe cierto dato en especifico que se usa como variable en una formula que quiero reemplazar por algun nuevo valor
Aqui mi JSON

```
[{"id_formulas": 2, "formulas": "dias > x && dias > 0", "condicion": 0}]
```

Por ejemplo reemplazar días por una cantidad de días.

Aqui mi codigo

```
@app.route('/test/<int:id_formulas>')

def test(id_formulas):
        try:
            cursorobject = connectionObject.cursor()

            cursorobject.execute("SELECT * FROM formulas WHERE id_formulas = %s", id_formulas)
            rows = cursorobject.fetchall()
            ObjetJSON = json.dumps(rows)
            print(ObjetJSON)
            return ObjetJSON
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exeception occured:{}".format(e))
```